# What is the purpose of using throw after function signature in c++?

Tags: c++, exception

As per I understood, exception in c++ will be call explicitly by using throw statement

```
 void exp()
 {
    try{    
       int a,b=0;
       if(b==0)
       {
          throw b; // called explicity
       }
       a=10/b;
    }
    catch(...)
    {

       //   cout<<"Exception called\n"<<e;
    }    
 }
```

Given the following snippet:

```
void myfunction(.............)throw(SQLEXCEPTION)
{
    //my stuff
}
```

1. What is the purpose of using throw after function signature.
2. Where catch block can be defined for such throw.
3. Will it handle the exception implicitly.
4. If not handle implicity, at which situations the throw execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw()` in the function signature specifies the exceptions a function may throw.

Example:

```
void foo() throw(std::runtime_error, std::logic_error);
```

`throw()` with no arguments means the function throws no exceptions

Exception specification is deprecated and its usage is not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

A `throw()` specification on a function declaration indicates which specific exception(s) the function is allowed to throw to the caller.  It is a kind of contract so the caller knows what to expect.  If no `throw()` is specified, the function is allowed to throw any exception.  If the `throw()` is empty, the function is not allowed to throw any exceptions.  So, in your example, `myfunction()` is allowed to throw only `SQLEXCEPTION` and derived exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

**1-** The use of `throw(type-list)` after the function signature is so that you or  the programmer who will read your code will know that this function can only throw the types that you specifed in `type-list`.

```
void f()throw(){};// This function can not throw any object of any type.
void f()throw(A){}; // you can throw any A object + 
                   // any object of a type drived from A if A is a User-defined Type
```

If you throw an object of a type that is not in the exception specification, `std::unexpected()` function will be called.
**2-** There is no catch block here. the `throw(type-list)` after function signature is just insurance that this function wont throw any type except objects of type in `type-list`.

What you are using is called Exception specification, one example of it's use is like this:

```
    int f(int x)throw(int){
             if (x==0) throw 0;
              return x;
    }

    int main(){
    try{
        f(0);  
       }
    catch(int e){
     // something
       }
    }
```

You can remember two things:

**i)** Don't use exception specification since they are deprecated.
**ii)** If you have to use them, then you must now that some compilers will refuse to inline a function just because it has an exception specification.

---

**Update:**

```
void f()throw(int){
      try{
       // code goes here ...
       throw 1.1; // note this is throwing a float
      }
      catch(float){
      // exception handled
      }

  }
```

In this example you wont get any errors, even if you throw an exception of type `float`, which is not specified in the function exception specification which only allow you to throw object of type `int`. This is because you handled the exception inside the function.

---

```
void f()throw(int){
        throw 1;

 }
 int main(){
       try{
           f();

       }
       catch(int){// exception handled}

 }
```

You should always put a function that you think may throw an exception inside a `try-block`, the code above will get executed fine since `f()` throw an `int` and it got handled.

---

```
void f()throw(int){

   throw 1.1; // note this is throwing a float

 }

 int main(){
    try{ 
       f();

    }
  catch(...){//}
 }
```

This will result in function call of `std::unexpected()` because your function `f()` throw an exception of type `float` which is not in the function exception specification.

Comment: as per your statement "wont throw any type except the objects of type in type-list" But watch here am throwing char* how it is possible... It is catched by catch block http://ideone.com/h2msQ5

Comment: @Vinoth in your case the object that you throw inside your function is ALWAYS handled inside your function, this means that exp() doesn't throw any exception. we say a function throw an exception when it's not handled inside the function body.

Comment: "function throw an exception when it's not handled inside the function body" Is this statement means , "If any exception is not handled by our function it will throw it program will not crash". Am  correct. For eg if divide by zero is place inside the function and if throw logical error exception after funtion signature. the program will not crash...

Answer (score -3):

The purpose of the throw is that the programmer is creating an exceptions.

For example you could have a custom array object that checks to see if it is in bounds and if it is not then throw an exception.